# Propensity score matching sample size

Tags: sample-size, propensity-scores, intervention-analysis

I am considering doing a propensity score matching to evaluate the effectiveness of a intervention. However, i only have 193 cases in my treatment group. I have a lot in control group. My outcome is a categorical variable with five categories. in this case, do I have enough sample size? How can I determine how big the sample size for the treatment group is enough?

Thank you!